Given the probability of each person using a PC and for how long, how many PCs does a company need?
I made up the following exercise that I'm not able to solve.
Part 1
There are $N$ people who all need a PC for their work. Each person works independently from each other. 
They don't use a PC everyday, there is a probability $d$ that they will need a PC.
What is the number $n_0$ of PC that I need, so that the probability that all PCs are taken is less than 0.1?
My solution: let $H(n)$ be the probability that $n$ PCs are busy in the same day.
$$H(n)=(d)^n(1-d)^{N-n}$$
i.e. the probability that $n$ people need a PC, and $N-n$ people do not. Now just find the $n_0$ such that $H(n_0)<0.1$.
Part 2
Assume now the same question as part one, but add one key fact: when a person uses a PC, he will not use it for the whole day but only for X% of the day. 
Each person uses a PC with no interruption and it can be in any random moment of the day. Say, for instance, X=25% -> 6h per day is the time slot used by each person, but this block of 6h can be anywhere in the 24h of a day.
My approach would be to use the solution of step one and multiply times the probability that timeslots overlap:
$$H(n)=(d)^n(1-d)^{N-n} \cdot P(overlap)$$
Assuming that the solution to part 1 is correct, how do you calculate $P(overlap)$?

Your solution to Part 1 is not correct as you are not taking into account the number of different subsets of $n$ people within the total $N$. Look up the binomial distribution.
